# tpl dataflow: fixed buffer size without throwing items away

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

After playing around with dataflow I encountered a new problem. I would like to limit the inputqueue of all blocks. My producingblock (ActionBlock) is creating 5000 elements really fast and posts them to an broadcastblock. So if i set the BoundedCapacity of the broadcastblock to 100 he throws a lot of data away. But I would prefer the producingblock to wait for new slots in the inputqueue of my bufferblock.

Is there any way to get rid of this problem?

Comment: Related: [BroadcastBlock with Guaranteed Delivery in TPL Dataflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22127660/broadcastblock-with-guaranteed-delivery-in-tpl-dataflow)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's exactly what `BufferBlock` is for. If you set its `BoundedCapacity` and it gets full, it will postpone receiving any messages until someone consumes them. This means that for example `Post()` will block and `SendAsync()` will return an unfinished `Task`.

**EDIT:** There is no built-in block that sends to multiple targets and never throws data away. But you can easily build one yourself from `ActionBlock` and sending loop:

```
static ITargetBlock<T> CreateMultipleTargetsBlock<T>(
    IEnumerable<ITargetBlock<T>> targets, int boundedCapacity)
{
    var targetsList = targets.ToList();

    var block = new ActionBlock<T>(
        async item =>
        {
            foreach (var target in targetsList)
            {
                await target.SendAsync(item);
            }
        },
        new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { BoundedCapacity = boundedCapacity });

    // TODO: propagate completion from block to targets

    return block;
}
```

This code assumes that you don't need to clone the data for each target and that the list of targets never changes. Modifying the code for that should be fairly simple.

Comment: First of all - thanks. I was absolutly blind ... . But I need a block, which can send messages to multiple recievers. Thats not possbile with a bufferblock. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: What should happen when one of the receivers is slow? Should the other receivers be required to wait for it? (I'm assuming that the receivers also have `BoundedCapacity` set, otherwise, setting `BoundedCapacity` on the buffer would basically have no effect.)

Comment: yes, BoundedCapacity is always to the same value. Its also true, that the other recievers need to wait for the slow operation.

Comment: In my experience, `Post()` does not block when called on a `BufferBlock` filled to capacity.